# Problem with RecyclerView, moves to the last position

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm a recyclerView with a custom adapter. In this moment, I've seven items. The first time that open the activity my recyclerView show me in the first element, but but if I go out and go back in, it is positioned in the last element. It seems that makes a autoscroll.

The strange thing (I do not know if it has to do) is that I put a line in the log, in the GetItemViewType method and the first time I open, I get this:

```
 D/POSITION(30978): 0
 E/POSITION(30978): 0
 D/POSITION(30978): 1
 E/POSITION(30978): 1
 D/POSITION(30978): 0
 E/POSITION(30978): 0
 D/POSITION(30978): 1
 E/POSITION(30978): 1
 D/POSITION(30978): 0
 E/POSITION(30978): 0
 D/POSITION(30978): 1
 E/POSITION(30978): 1
```

And when I go out and come back in, I get this:

```
 D/POSITION(30978) : 0
 E/POSITION(30978) : 0
 D/POSITION(30978) : 1
 E/POSITION(30978) : 1
 D/POSITION(30978) : 1
 E/POSITION(30978) : 1
 D/POSITION(30978) : 4
 E/POSITION(30978) : 4
 D/POSITION(30978) : 4
 E/POSITION(30978) : 4
 D/POSITION(30978) : 5
 E/POSITION(30978) : 5
 D/POSITION(30978) : 6
 E/POSITION(30978) : 6
 D/POSITION(30978) : 7
 E/POSITION(30978) : 7
 D/POSITION(30978) : 3
 E/POSITION(30978) : 3
 D/POSITION(30978) : 3
 E/POSITION(30978) : 3
 D/POSITION(30978) : 4
 E/POSITION(30978) : 4
 D/POSITION(30978) : 5
 E/POSITION(30978) : 5
 D/POSITION(30978) : 6
 E/POSITION(30978) : 6
 D/POSITION(30978) : 7
 E/POSITION(30978) : 7
```

My layout is:

```xml
<MvxRecyclerView
     android:clipToPadding="false"
     android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

My activity:

```cs
protected override void OnViewModelSet()
{
     SetContentView(Resource.Layout.myActivity);
     _recyclerViewAdapter = new ClassRecyclerViewAdapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);
     _recyclerView = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.myRecyclerView);
     _recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
     _recyclerView.Adapter = _recyclerViewAdapter;
     _recyclerView.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnScrollChangedListener(this);
}
```

And my adapter:

```cs
public class ClassRecyclerViewAdapter : MvxRecyclerAdapter
{
     public ClassRecyclerViewAdapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
            : base(bindingContext) => HasStableIds = true;

     public override int GetItemViewType(int position) 
     {
          Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ILogger>().LogMessage("POSITION", position.ToString());
          return ViewTypeFactory.ViewType((MyItems)GetItem(position));
      }

     public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
      {
          var bc = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(parent.Context, BindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder);
          return ViewHolderFactory.ViewType(viewType, parent, bc);
      }

      public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
      {
          base.OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);
          var holder = holder as ItemViewHolder;
          holder.Bind();
      }

      public override long GetItemId(int position)
      {
          var fi = (MyItems)GetItem(position);
          return fi.Id;
       }
}
```

I need that always show me in the first element.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Hey @jmlg You mentioned "but if I go out and go back in, it is positioned in the last element". Could you please explain that? Are you saying that if you go out of the app and open the app again, the page scrolls to the bottom of the view and selects the last element?

Comment: Hi @Saamer. Thank for you interest. When I say "but if I go out and go back in, it is positioned in the last element"  it means that with the recyclerview on the screen, I press my back button, which takes me to another screen that has a button, I press my button to return to the recyclerview and it automatically drops to the last item of the recyclerview, it is always presented in the last position.

Comment: In your OnResume, after base.OnResume(); could you try recyclerView.SmoothScrollToPosition(0); or 1. Or use that line in end after everything on that page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`SmoothScrollToPosition(int position)` scrolls to show the item at the bottom of the screen.

You can use:

```
 ScrollToPositionWithOffset(int position, int offset)
```

with `offset=0`. That's however not smooth.

I'm not sure wether you can extend the `RecyclerView` to feature something like `SmoothScrollToPositionFromTop(int position)`, which is available e.g. in AbsListView